# Java - multiple return statements - first one not returning?

Tags: java, android, debugging, return

I'm toying around with some Android programming, and was in the process of writing a couple methods to open and close a file.  Well, I wanted to do some basic checks on the file and return true if the conditions were satisfied, or return false if it reaches the end of the method.

I was testing these with AndroidTestCase, and after I added a required permission to my manifest to fix my "canRead()" call, I started stepping through them.  I see the debugger hit my "return true" statement, but then stepping over that, it moves on to the following line "return false" instead of actually returning.

I know I could wrap the "return false" in an else block, but am just curious why the function continues to execute after supposedly returning.  Is a return statement inside an "if" block just returning out of the block, or should it be returning out of the whole function call?

```
public boolean OpenFile(String testFile) {
    myFile = new File(testFile);
    if (myFile.exists() && myFile.isFile() && myFile.canRead()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean CloseFile() {
    if (myFile != null ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to where's `return` located, the problem is that the condition doesn't met.

Comment: Try to avoid the `if(expression) return true/false;` pattern. It could be `return myFile.exists() && myFile.isFile() && myFile.canRead();` and `return myFile != null;`.

Comment: return always returns from the function call immediately when executed. What you describe isn't happening. You may interpret wrong what you're seeing when debugging. Add some log statements and show us the output.

Comment: try to print before returning a value,. to see the actual behavior

Comment: @AlexisC. There will be additional logic inside that expression, "return true" is just a placeholder for testing my testing.

Comment: @ci_ I see that it is just a result of debugging / stepping through... when I checked the output value of the function it was returning true as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the condition in your `if` statement is true, then `return true;` gets executed and the method terminates.

To check this, just put a `println(...)` before the `return false;` instruction, you will see that it won't be executed. Check again your debug, you probably got confused by the tool.

Comment: Yep, I was just getting confused by how the stepping was working.  After I set a breakpoint on the call in the test method, I was able to verify that it was returning true as expected.